# php script does not work. but if I include it in other file, it works?

Tags: php

I have this half-written script, and it will not work at all

```
<?php

function hit_count() {
        echo $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $ip_file = file('ip.txt');
        foreach ($ip_file as $ip) {
            $ip_single = trim($ip);
            if ($ip_address==$ip_single) {
                $found = false;
            } else {
                $found = true;
            }
        }

        if ($found==false) {
        echo 'IP not found.';
        }
}
?>
```

even the first line will not display anything.
but lo and behold, if I include it in this file

```
<?php
include 'unique-counter.php';

hit_count();
?>
```

the "echo" displays my ip.

how does that happen?

Comment: did you called hit_count() in first file?!

Answer (score 6):

Your script by itself only defines a function, it does not call it.

Add `hit_count();` to the standalone script.